# Not able to click and element using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate 'Tableau' login screen and download reports flow. Everything works fine till I reach the 'Download' button. The first problem is I am NOT able to right click on the Download button and do an 'Inspect' in Chrome which is weird. I somehow am able to find the xpath by going through the whole page. When i try to click it I get "Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[4]/span[1]"}".

The code that I am using is mentioned below:

```
String xPath = "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[4]/span[1]";

    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20))
       .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xPath)));

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)).click();
```

The page layout is like this from where I am picking the xpath

```
    <div class="tabToolbarButton tab-widget" style="-webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; width: 77.4px;">
<span class="tabToolbarButtonImg tab-icon-download"></span>
<span class="tabToolbarButtonText">Download</span></div>
<span class="tabToolbarButtonImg tab-icon-download"></span>
<span class="tabToolbarButtonText">Download</span>
    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. What could be the reason for not able to 'Inspect'??

Comment: to click on first span,  use this as cssSelctor and check what happens     div.tabToolbarButton.tab-widget >span.tabToolbarButtonImg.tab-icon-download

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to right click on the element, you can still right click anywhere on the page and select Inspect this element. You can then grab little binocular icon(tool tip message-select an element in the page to inspect it) and point it to the desired web element to check the xpath. 
1st thing you need to check if you are writing xpath correctly. On a chrome you can do that without any plugin. On the developer window(same window which gets open when you select Inspect Element option), look for Console window and write your xpath as mentioned below and hit Enter.

```
$x("Write x path here")
```

for e.g. xpath for google search box

```
$x("//input[@id='lst-ib']")
```

I'm not sure why you writing absolute xpath. Its a bad practice. You can write x path for Download button in better way.
e.g.

```
(//span[@class='tabToolbarButtonText'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem. So it seems the web page I was trying to automate has used frames. That is why even after providing the xpath the element was not getting clicked. I had to use 'switchTo.frame' in order to get the frame in focus and then I was able to click the element. Thanks for all the responses.

What I have still not understood is that why I was not able to inspect the element directly but that is a different question.